# BASH: "Are We There Yet" - A Seemingly Simple Reaction-Based Script

Tags: bash

My professor assigned me a script to work on that I can't seem to understand.

HOW THE SCRIPT IS SUPPOSED TO WORK:

It is supposed to ask the user "Are we there yet?" (yes, à la The Simpsons) and the user is supposed to respond in 0, standing for NO, or 1, standing for YES.

If 0 then the script will output threatening messages with an increment variable called $THREATCOUNTER before asking "Are we there yet?" again.

If the user continues saying 0, the threatening messages get more aggressive until the user says 0 ten times. At the tenth time, the script outputs "DIE." and the program ends.

If the user says 1 at any point, the script outputs "Yay." and the program again ends.

THE CODE:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Are we there yet?"

read input

if [ $input = 1 ]
        then
                echo "Yay!"

        else
                COUNTER=1
                while [ $COUNTER -lt 10 ] do
                        echo "Are we there yet?"
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 1] do
                        echo "We better get there soon or you'll be sorry!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 2 ] do
                        echo "Oh, if you were any slower you wouldn't be mentally capable of driving!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 3 ] do
                        echo "You better start driving faster or you're gonna be begging for mommy!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 4 ] do
                        echo "I have an idea how you can get their faster! Put your |CENSORED| foot on the |CENSORED| pedal!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 5 ] do
                        echo "Drive faster |CENSORED| |CENSORED|! Drive faster or I'll rip your legs off, you're not using them anyways!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 6 ] do
                        echo "For the love of |CENSORED|, can't you actually get there! We don't have all |CENSORED| day!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 7 ] do
                        echo "Oh my |CENSORED|, why do you have to drive as though you're your |CENSORED| great grandmother?"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 8 ] do
                        echo "Who in |CENSORED| green earth would let you drive, you torturous madman? Drive! Drive!! DRIVE!!!"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 9 ] do
                        echo "Oh for |CENSORED| sake, why haven't we gotten there yet, you worthless stick rider?"
                fi
                        COUNTER++
                if [ $COUNTER -eq 10 ] do
                        echo "DIE."
                fi
fi
```

THE ERRORS:

```
./arewethereyet.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./arewethereyet.sh: line 17: `      fi'
```

What do?

Comment: `if ... do` is wrong. `if ... ; then` is right.

Comment: It helps to read the documentation for a language you intend to write a program in.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for if is:

```
if [ "0" -eq "0" ]; then echo blah; fi
```

The Syntax for a while is:

```
 while [ "1" -eq "0" ]; do echo blah; done
```

You should also look into replacing the series of if with either several if/else if statements, add some continues within the if blocks, or replace the ifs with a switch.

You should also restructure where you are getting input.